# How to optimize a function that matches observations according to certain criteria

Tags: r, function, for-loop, optimization, purrr

I am looking for a more efficient way of doing an operation with a given dataframe.

```
 library(purrr)
 library(dplyr)
```

Here is a step by step description:

First, there is the function `possible_matches`, that for each observation `i` in `df`, gives the index of rows that are possibly matchable to `i`, which are going to be used on the next step:

```
 possible_matches <-  function(i, df) {
  k1 <- df$j[df$id_0 == df$id_0[i]]
  j2 <- setdiff(df$j, k1)
  k2 <- map(j2, ~ df$j[df$id_0[.] == df$id_0])
  k3 <- map(k2, ~ map(.x,  ~ df$j[df$Year[k1] == df$Year[.] & 
                                    df$Quarter[k1] == df$Quarter[.]]
  ) %>% unlist(.))
  k4 <- map(k3,  ~ length(.) == 0) %>% unlist()
  j2[k4]
}
```

Basically, it takes all rows with the same `id` to `i`, and then filter some out according to some criteria. This function is used inside function `match1`, which loops through all rows given by `possible_matches`, filtering out more of them according to some other criteria (simplified here):

```
 match_1 <-  function(i, df) {
j <- possible_matches(i, df) 
if (is_empty(j)) {
  out <- i
} else {
  
  g1 <-
    abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= 5
     out <- ifelse(!g1, i, j[g1])    
}
return(out)
}
```

Since `match1` possibly returns multiple observations per row, I have to try to group all paired ones as much as I can. I do this by defining:

```
modes <- function(x, y) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(y, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}
```

Running it inside function `equalize_indices`, which also splits `df` into groups so that there is no looping through unnecessary rows:

```
 equalize_indices <- function(df, prev_id) {
    df1 <- df %>%
      group_split()
    
    w <- df1 %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
            nrow() %>%
            seq())
    
    df1 <- map(df1, ~.x %>%
                 mutate(j = row_number())
    )
    x <- map2(w, df1, ~ map(.x, match_1, df = .y))
    
    z <- map(x, function(x){
      map(x, ~ modes(., x) %>%
            min(.))
      })
    
    df3 <- map2(df1, z,  ~.x %>%
                  mutate(index = .y) %>%
                  group_by(index) %>%
                  mutate(index = min({{prev_id}})) %>%
                  select(-j)
    )
    df <- bind_rows(df3)
    return(df)
  }
```

**EDIT**
Finally, here is some larger data with the expected output:

```
set.seed(1)

DF <- data.frame(
  UPA = 1,
  Quarter = sample(1:4, 8, replace  = TRUE),
  Year = sample(2010:2015, 8, replace  = TRUE),
  id_0 = sample(2:10, 8, replace  = TRUE),
  V2009 = c(19, 22, 17, 10, 37, 19, 22, 17)
  ) %>%
  group_by(UPA)

  DF %>%
  equalize_indices(prev_id = id_0)
```

**Here is my question**: it takes too long to run this procedure with a data frame with 25k rows (about 30 min) using more conditionalities. Why is this? Is there some way to turn the process faster? This needs to be scalable to very large data frames. I know looping may take time, but by using `group_split` inside `equalize_indices`, I can turn the loops smaller.

How can I optimize this procedure? - It basically is a process splitting a dataset, eliminating unmatchable observations to each row, picking the most common matched index for each row, and then binding the rows again.

I am not even sure which exact part is so time consuming.

Comment: Can you describe what the heuristic is for assigning indexes to records in your output data.frame object? You've demonstrated a highly detailed approach to solving a problem here, but it would also be helpful to describe it in more abstract terms.

Comment: The slowdown is likely related to all of the list - R will have to extract and allocate memory a lot for all of these ```map()``` calls. The second slowdown is that you have a lot of filters similar to```df$prev_0 == df$prev_0[i]```.  I am looking into it but heuristics would be nice as real performance gain would need a significant refactor.

Comment: Okay, in more abstract terms: I want for each row ```i``` ind ```df``` to find other rows that can be "matched" to it according to some criteria given by ```match1```. Since I don't want to loop through all rows every time,```possible_matches``` shortens the loop in ```match1``` by removing rows that cannot be matched.  Each ```i``` can be matched to multiple units - to pick one that maximizes the chance of choosing the same index for every ```i```, I use ```modes``` to pick the element in ```match1(i, df)``` i that is the most common when considering the whole set of rows

Comment: As for what ```possible_matches``` does: it removes from ```1:nrow(df)``` for each ```i```: rows that have the same ```id_0``` as ```i```, rows that have either the same ```Year``` and ```Quarter``` to```i``` or rows that have the same ```id_0``` as some row with the same ```Year``` and ```Quarter``` to i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach:

First we create a new function that instead of returning an entire `data.frame`, we just return the index

```r
equalize_indices2 = function(DF) {
  n = nrow(DF)
  if (n == 1L) return(DF$id_0) ## short-circuit; no need to do any comparisons!
  j = seq(n)
  
  ##check equalities up front so we only have to do it once for all rows
  id_0_eq = outer(DF$id_0, DF$id_0, `==`)
  year_quarter_eq = outer(DF$Year, DF$Year, `==`) & outer(DF$Quarter, DF$Quarter, `==`)
  
  ##pre-allocate vector
  ans = vector('integer', n)
  
  ##simplify logic; id_0 == id_0 but none of the other elements are equal (e.g., id_0[1] != id_0[2])
  only_diag_true = sum(id_0_eq) == n
  
  for (i in j) {
    ######replacement of possible matches#######
    if (only_diag_true) { 
      j2 = j[-i]
      tmp = j2[!year_quarter_eq[j2, i]]
    } else {
      ##TODO match expected output of larger dataset. May be due to downstream issues.
      k1 = j[id_0_eq[i, ]]
      j2 = j[-k1]
      # k4 = unlist(Map(function(x) j[!year_quarter_eq[k1, j[id_0_eq[x, ]]]], j2), use.names = FALSE)
      k4 = vapply(j2, function(x) length(j[year_quarter_eq[k1, j[id_0_eq[x, ]]]]) == 0L, NA)
      # k4 = unlist(Map(function(x) j[!year_quarter_eq[k1, x]], k2), use.names = FALSE)
      
      tmp = j2[k4]
    }
    
    #######replacement of match_1##########
    if (!length(tmp)) { ##This happens when nrow(df) == 1L or the year and quarters match...I think
      out = i
    } else {
      g1 = abs(DF$V2009[i] - DF$V2009[tmp]) <= 5
      out = ifelse(!g1, i, tmp[g1])  
    }
    
    ########replacement of modes#######
    ans[i] = if (length(out) == 1L) out else out[which.max(out)]
  } 
  
  ## replacement of df3 call in OP
  index = ave(DF$id_0, ans, FUN = function(x) {x[1L]})
  return(index)
}
```

Then, we modify `data.table` in place using the function we just created:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, index := equalize_indices2(.SD), by = UPA]
df

##      UPA Quarter  Year  id_0 V2009 index
##    <num>  <char> <num> <int> <num> <int>
## 1:     1       1  2012     1    19     1
## 2:     1       1  2012     2    22     1
## 3:     1       1  2011     3    17     1
## 4:     1       1  2012     4    10     4
## 5:     2       1  2012     5    37     5
```

The main benefits are that we minimize equality operators because for each `UPA` group, we only look at the equalities once per group instead of for each row. The other nice thing is that we do not have to deal with as many nested lists. In fact, this includes no lists.

This is still a WIP, I am going to do the `TODO` logic line later today but this works for the current dataset. If you provide a larger dataset, I will also test against that as well.

As far as performance, this is more than 100x faster than OP. Note `check = FALSE` because they return different classes (e.g., `data.table` vs. only a `data.frame`)

```r
dt = as.data.table(df)
bench::mark(dt_new_fx = dt[, index := equalize_indices2(.SD), by = UPA],
            OP = {df %>%
              equalize_indices(prev_id = id_0)},
            check = FALSE
)

## # A tibble: 2 x 13
##   expression   min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr> <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 dt_new_fx  370us  390us    2439.     32.5KB
## 2 OP          46ms   46ms      21.8    39.5KB
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can't test it right now to give some feedback. Just a question: is the specific use of data.table really advantageous in this case? I am not really familiar with it, much more so with dplyr, and thus would be easier for me to adapt and explain the procedure if using a tidyverse analogue

Comment: Note, the function is just base R. The ```data.table``` part could be translated to ```dplyr``` but I had an error when trying ```dplyr```. I will likely post a question about the error as I was surprised. To your point, ```dt[, var := x, by = grp]``` is not that different than ```df= df%>%group_by(grp)%>%mutate(var = x)``` although ```data.table``` for your example

Comment: oh, good, but my point was that for this case, the poor performance was not actually due to dplyr, right?

Comment: Yes. The poor performance was due to deep use of nesting and having to repeat the same equality comparisons multiple times.

Comment: ```if (!length(tmp)) { ##This happens when nrow(df) == 1L or the year and quarters match...I think
      out = i
    }``` as for this comment in your code: this happens in ```match1``` when nothing was paired in ```possible_matches```. When does this occur: when all rows in DF either have the same ```Year/Quarter``` as ```i```, or the same ```id_0``` or have the same ```id_0``` as some row that has the same ```Year/Quarter``` to ```i```

Comment: I'm glad this worked. You said this took 30 minutes to run. How long does it take now?

Comment: I couldn't test yet. I am not sure if everything is done, though. I guess the ```TODO``` refers to needing to do more filtering in ```possible_matches```?. I've already rewarded the bounty, though

Comment: I've posted a larger DF, as required

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Can you confirm that on your larger dataset, that all results of index should be 6?  I am working on changes but am not getting the same answer as you.

Comment: sorry for taking so long - I don't get all 6's - the result is actually ```2 2 2 3 7 2 2 2``` Did you use the seed? It should give ```id_0 = 5 2 7 3 7 4 10 2```

Comment: I copied your code exactly. Could you ```dput``` your larger dataset? I'm thinking I have issues with the replacement of your mode fx

Comment: Sorry, just saw your expected id_0 as well. Mine is this ``` 7  8 10  6  6 10 10  6```. Note there was change between R 3.5.x and 3.6.x  on setting seeds which could explain the difference. Also, I edited my answer to include where I currently am at in case I accidently delete it.