# Generalizing process of finding matching indexes - possible mistake on subsetting

Tags: r, subset

consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:2, 2:1, 2:3),
                 x = c(1:3, 3:1))
```

I want, for each row `i`, to fill a vector with all row numbers that:

- Do not have the same `id` as `i`.
- Do not have the same `x` as `i`
- Do not have the same `x` as some other row that has the same `id` as `i`
- Do not have the same `id` as some other row that has the same `x` as `i`

For `df`, consider `i = 1`. Then we should get `2` and `5`.
For the specific case of `i = 1`, here is how I've written code that gets these indices:

```
i <- 1
a <- outer(df$id, df$id, `==`)
b <- outer(df$x, df$x, `==`)

j <- 1:6

ind_a <- setdiff(j[a[,i]],i)
ind_b <- setdiff(j[b[,i]],i)

remove <- union_all(which(b[,ind_a]), which(a[,ind_b]),i)
setdiff(j, remove)
```

However, this does not seem to work for other values of `i`. For `i = 2` the subsetting wouldn't work,
because `b[,ind_a]` has more than two columns, so that `which(b[,ind_a])` is `3  4  8 11`, outside of `j = 1:6`. The answer would be `1` and `6`, which is correct, although I am not sure if it would always work.

Can someone find a safer alternative? It is paramount that the answer uses

```
a <- outer(df$id, df$id, `==`)
    b <- outer(df$x, df$x, `==`)
```

So that the equality comparisons only need to be made once, and not for every `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done in the end:

```
map(j, function(i){
  
  a1 <- setdiff(j[a[, i]], i)
  b1 <- setdiff(j[b[, i]], i)
  rm_a <- which(rowSums(b[, a1, drop = FALSE]) > 0)
  rm_b <- which(rowSums(a[, b1, drop = FALSE]) > 0)
  
  setdiff(j, union_all(rm_a, rm_b, i))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `outer` here :

```
i <- 1
which(!df$id %in% unique(df$id[df$x == df$x[i]]) & 
      !df$x %in% unique(df$x[df$id == df$id[i]]))
#[1] 2 5

i <- 2
which(!df$id %in% unique(df$id[df$x == df$x[i]]) & 
      !df$x %in% unique(df$x[df$id == df$id[i]]))

#[1] 1 6
```

Comment: I have used it because this previous answer used it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64402786/7812142. In it part of the solution of optimizing my function involved outer. The present issue actually would be within that context, which explains the outer. I would be glad to not use outer if it did not slowed down that procedure